# C Program about Password Validation not working

Tags: c, validation, passwords

I wrote a program which is supposed to check if an entered password has an uppercase letter , a lowercase letter and a number. It won't return anything if the password is valid and if the password is invalid it should say "Not a valid password!". But this program doesn't work and I don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  char pass[20];
  int a, i=0;
  printf("Enter your password. It must contain an uppercase and a lowercase letter with a number. Password should be less than 19 characters.\n ");
  scanf(" %s", pass);
  a = strlen(pass);

  /* Checking if an uppercase letter is present*/

  for(i=0; i<a ; i++)
  {
    if(!isupper(pass[i] && i!=(a-1)))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if (!isupper(pass[i]))
    {
        printf("Not a valid Password!");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
  }

  /* Checking if a lowercase letter is present */

  for(i=0; i<a ; i++)
  {
    if(!islower(pass[i] && i!=(a-1)))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if (!islower(pass[i]))
    {
        printf("Not a valid Password!");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
  }

  /* Checking if a number is present*/

  for(i=0; i<a ; i++)
  {
    if(!isdigit(pass[i] && i!=(a-1)))
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if (!isdigit(pass[i]))
    {
        printf("Not a valid Password!");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Give an example case of the expected result and the result you get.

Comment: For example when I enter "rabbit" as password, it should show "Not a valid password", but it shows nothing (which happens if the password is valid).

Comment: Your program logic and your overall approach look totally wrong to me.

Comment: Not directly related, but why don't you name the variable containing the length of the password `length`, or `passwordlength `instead of `a`? That would make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong, you want `isupper(pass[i])`, instead you have the logical and in there as well. It's the same with `isdigit`. Still, even once you've fixed that, your code will print "Not a valid password" twice if you enter "rabbit".

Comment: Please do not edit your code after you received comments and answers. People spent time to provide feedback for your problem which is rendered useless if you change your code. Questions should not be moving targets.

Comment: Seems like a good job for a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have copied the code of the loop that checks uppercase, and used it in the other loops. The `else if` part in each loop contains the exact same condition.

A better way to do this would be using three flags:

```
int lower_flag = 0, upper_flag = 0, digit_flag = 0;
for(i=0 ; i<a ; i++) {
    if(isupper(pass[i])) upper_flag=1;
    else if(islower(pass[i])) lower_flag=1;
    else if(isdigit(pass[i])) digit_flag=1;
}
if(upper_flag && lower_flag && digit_flag)
    printf("Valid");
else
    printf("Invalid");
```

Comment: I am a beginner and didn't know what flags were. I'll surely check them now, thanks!

Comment: `Flag` is just a term, used to say that some part of the code has changed, according to some rules. For example, if you've played "Minesweeper", if you don't want to mark that a tile shouldn't be clicked, you "flag" it.

Comment: Are int and bool interchangeable when we use '1 and 0' instead of 'true and false'?

Comment: @KrutikDesai Yes, they are interchangeable. Internally, `true`is `1` and `false` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 3 loops to check the valid password in your case.
You can do as below with one loop. All you need is 3 `bool` variables to mark `upper,lower & digits` presence in your password.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int main()
{
  char pass[20];
  int a, i=0;
  bool upperPresent = false,lowerPresent = false,digitPresent = false;
  printf("Enter your password. It must contain an uppercase and a lowercase letter with a number. Password should be less than 19 characters.\n ");
  scanf(" %s", pass);
  a = strlen(pass);

/* Checking if an uppercase letter is present*/

for(i=0; i<a ; i++){
    if(isupper(pass[i])){
      upperPresent = true;
    }
   else if (islower(pass[i])){
      lowerPresent = true;
    }else if (isdigit(pass[i])){
     digitPresent = true;
    }

  }

  if (upperPresent && lowerPresent && digitPresent)
   printf("Valid password\n");
  else
   printf("invalid Password\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a bool that is triggered if you find an upper or a lower or a number and then exit out of the loop, because right now you are just traversing the whole string. Also you are checking for an upper in the third loop again.